# How to use Flow Layout inside a Panel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, panel, flowlayout

### Here is the code with problem:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class xtemp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1067, 600);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x000000));
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel_red = new JPanel();
        panel_red.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel_red.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 300);

        JPanel panel_blue = new JPanel();
        panel_blue.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel_blue.setBounds(10, 310, 300, 300);

        JPanel panel_green = new JPanel();
        panel_green.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel_green.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        panel_green.setBounds(310, 10, 800, 600);
        panel_green.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 9, 16));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
            panel_green.add(new JButton(String.format("%02d", i)));

        frame.add(panel_red);
        frame.add(panel_green);
        frame.add(panel_blue);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### And this is the output of the code:

[image]

### I want an output similar to this:

[image]

I want to use multiple panels and give different layouts to different panels within a frame. I basically want that any buttons inside the `panel_green` must automatically get adjusted according to the space available, irrespective of the fact that it is a panel, not a frame as shown in the second gif/image.

Comment: You're still using null layouts. Why?

Comment: setting the bounds of your panels will prevent them from stretching with the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `null` layouts.  Use Swing layout managers.

I was able to create the following GUI:

[image: Original GUI]

When I maximized the GUI:

[image: Maximized GUI]

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a `JFrame` with a default `BorderLayout`.

I created a west `JPanel` to hold the red `JPanel` and the blue `JPanel`.  You didn't say what you wanted to happen to the red and blue `JPanel` when maximized, so I used a `BoxLayout`.  That way, both `JPanels` would have an equal amount of height.

I created a green `JPanel` and used a `FlowLayout` for the `JButtons`.

Finally, I used methods to separate the creation of the `JFrame` from the creation of the `JPanels`.  That way, the code is much easier for other people to read, I can separate my concerns, and I can focus on one small part of the GUI at a time.

Here's the complete, runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BorderLayoutExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BorderLayoutExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Border Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createWestPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(createGreenPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createGreenPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton(String.format("%02d", i)));
        }

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createWestPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(createColoredPanel(Color.red));
        panel.add(createColoredPanel(Color.blue));

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createColoredPanel(Color color) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        return panel;
    }

}
```